# How can I mark a Bean as deprecated in Spring / Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In my codebase I currently have a restTemplate bean and a WebClient bean.
I would like to mark the restTemplate as deprecated as we want to progressively move away from it.

I have my 2 beans in my Configuration file:

```
    @Deprecated(message = "Please use WebClient instead")
    @Bean
    fun restTemplate(): RestTemplate =
        RestTemplateBuilder()
                .requestFactory { HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() }
                .build()

    @Bean
    fun baseWebClient(): WebClient =
        WebClient.builder().build()
```

However, when I autowire a RestTemplate, I don't see any deprecated warnings

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is not exactly what you are looking for but Spring provides a `DeprecatedBeanWarner` to log beans marked deprecated. This will not bring the IDE support you are hoping for but it will provide a log message.